# Why does my comparison clause always throw an IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, methods, comparison

I'm trying to create a calculator method and I want to use mathematical symbols in my case statement but my error checking keeps throwing an error.

I've tried moving my ELSE statements to the bottom in case it was an issue with sequencing somehow. When I add the variable to the end of my error message it appears to assign it correctly.

public static void calculator (double firstNumber, char operation, double secondNumber){

```
    if (operation != '+' || operation != '-' || operation != '*' || operation != '/' || operation !='%'){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must choose a number between 1 and 5 inclusive." + operation);
    }else{
        if(operation == '/' && secondNumber == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dividend cannot be zero.");
        }else{if(operation == '%' && secondNumber == 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dividend cannot be zero.");
            }else

                switch (operation){
                    case '+': System.out.println("1");
                    break;

                    case '-': System.out.println("2");
                    break;

                    case '*': System.out.println("3");
                    break;
```

....

Example of errors using +, %, and /:

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must choose a number between 1
> and 5 inclusive.+     at MathUtilites.calculator(MathUtilites.java:39)
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must choose a number between 1
> and 5 inclusive.%     at MathUtilites.calculator(MathUtilites.java:39)
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must choose a number between 1
> and 5 inclusive./     at MathUtilites.calculator(MathUtilites.java:39)
```

I am expecting it to just return a number between 1 and 5 which I will later be replacing with actual code.

Comment: You should replace `||` with `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment on your question suggested, you need to replace `||` with `&&` which will say *all of these must be true* instead of saying *any of these must be true*. Alter your code to look like this and it should work:

```
if (operation != '+' && operation != '-' && operation != '*' && operation != '/' && operation !='%'){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must choose a number between 1 and 5 inclusive." + operation);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (operation != '+' || operation != '-' || operation != '*' || operation != '/' || operation !='%'){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must choose a number between 1 and 5 inclusive." + operation);
```

should be

```
if (operation != '+' && operation != '-' && operation != '*' && operation != '/' && operation !='%'){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must choose a number between 1 and 5 inclusive." + operation);
    }
```

You should look up the boolean algebra related to `OR` and `AND` operators.